# How to change the var when selecting specific value on the Picker (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, swiftui

I need the `useRed` value to change to `true` when selecting `0%` in the UI picker (or `tipPercentage` becomes `4`).

I tried the following but the warning "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior" shows up and the `useRed` value remains `false`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {


    @State private var tipPercentage = 2
    @State private var useRed = false

    let tipPercentages = [10, 15, 20, 25, 0]

    var redCheck: Bool {
        if tipPercentage == 4 {
            useRed = true
        } else { useRed = false }
        return useRed
    }


    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            Form {

                Section (header: Text("How much tips do you weant to leave?")){
                    Picker("Tip percentage", selection:
                    $tipPercentage) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< tipPercentages.count) {
                            Text("\(self.tipPercentages[$0])%")
                        }

                        }
                      .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }.foregroundColor(redCheck ? .red : .black)

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the redCheck:

```
}.foregroundColor(tipPercentage == 4 ? .red : .black)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to set the color:

```
func updateColor() -> Color {
    if tipPercentage == 4 {
        return .red
    } else {
        return .black
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
.foregroundColor(self.updateColor())
```

Now you don't need the **redCheck** variable.